# Energy conservation equation for an object rolling up an incline

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, torque

An sphere of radius $R$ rolls up an incline. We can write mechanical energy conservation equations for this motion because neither does the normal or the frictional force do any work.

At the top of the incline the kinetic energy of this object will be zero and thus all of the mechanical energy will be In the potential form.

Assuming zero of potential $R$ above the horizontal,hence
$U_i=0$ where $U_i$ is the potential when the object is rolling on a horizontal plane.

[image]

At the top of the incline the potential energy of the object is $U_f=m g (h+ R \cos \theta-R)$.

When I compare this with other places on the internet I find that my equation is wrong.
They don't take into account the term

$R \cos \theta=h'$.
Why is this so. Am I wrong? Isn't this the way, we can write the energy equations?

(Links where they ignore this term:
https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-vivo&sxsrf=ALeKk03huUks-ybuFPC8eKFe6kuoXJme7Q%3A1610098556804&ei=fCf4X-zIMNGW4-EPsr6poAI&q=to+what+height+will+a+sphere+roll+up+an+incline&oq=to+what+height+will+a+sphere+roll+up+an+incline&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BwghEAoQoAFQmZwRWJbGEWDsyhFoAHABeAGAAccCiAGlFJIBBTItOS4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp#

https://www.concepts-of-physics.com/mechanics/rolling-without-slipping-of-rings-cylinders-and-spheres.php

Comment: That expression isn't homogenous $Uf=mgh+mgR\cos \theta−R.$ It would be   $Uf=mgh+mgR\cos \theta$ the question is that your sphere is not a dot object so there is an ambiguity defining its high, here it is a very interesting question of physic. But according to all theorem we use involving the center of gravity, it is logical is the sphere is homogenous to consider the high $h'=h+R\cos \theta.$.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake in writing the code. I've edited it.

Comment: If measuring to the center of mass, it should be (h-R).  Measure to the bottom of the sphere and you avoid the complications.

Answer (score 1):

*h* is a variable that represents some value, you get to define what value it represents. You can define *h* to be the difference in heights between the initial and final positions of the center of mass (as most people do), rather than the difference in heights at which the ball touches the incline (which you've done here). Neither definition of *h* is any more "correct" than the other, but it may make certain equations more convenient.

Lots of physics problems reduce objects to their centers of mass, so it'll often be more convenient to work with variables that respect that. By defining *h* with respect to the contact point rather than the CoM, you require an additional term involving the slope. But if you define *h* with respect to the CoM of the ball, the slope is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

$\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the link you provided. cos$\frac{\pi}{2}$ = 0.

Comment: The first link?

Comment: The first link is a google search what do I make out of it?